# Single malloc for multiple data type

Tags: c, arrays, linux, malloc, memory-alignment

I am trying to write a code for which I need multiple arrays of different data types. These arrays need to be dynamically allocated. I need to consider the performance so I want to allocate all the arrays with one `malloc` call.

For simple case, lets say I need one integer and one double precision floating point array. So, I am doing the following.

```
int *iA;
double *dA;
void *vp;
vp = malloc( (sizeof(int)+sizeof(double))*N ); // assume N is known at this point.

// now to set the array pointers I am doing the following.
iA = vp;
dA = (void*)(iA+N); // This is wrong!!
...
free(vp);
```

If address in vp is multiple of 8 (which usually is) and N is an odd number, dA is set to an address that is not a multiple of 8. This causes all sorts of problem. It should be fine if I interchange iA and dA assignment. This seems a simple solution but if I have more than two arrays and more than two different types, it might not solve the issue. I am not sure.

So, my question is, what is the best way (in terms of performance) to allocate memory if you need multiple array of different data types?

NOTE: I am on a 64bit Linux machine, compiling code with gcc-4.9.0.

Comment: Pretty sure you want `dA = (void*)iA + (N*sizeof(int))`

Comment: For N=3 and 64bit architecture (pointers are 8 bytes), here dA would point to iA + ( (3*4)*8=96bytes ). But we only allocated (8+4)*3=36bytes.

Comment: where did you get the extra `8` in `(3*4)*8`? just because pointers are 8 bytes doesn't mean that you have to increment them in multiples of 8.

Comment: My bad. I forgot that the sizeof(void) is actually 1. In that case, this expression has the same problem as mine. If N is odd, dA will start from a 4-byte aligned address, not 8.

Comment: Can you use C11? also, `malloc` is never guaranteed to return an 8-byte aligned address, so you shouldn't rely on that.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by C11. Yes. I know malloc is not guaranteed to return 8-byte aligned address, that's why in my original post I said "If vp is multiple of 8 and N is odd ....".

Comment: C11 is the latest standard of C, and you `malloc` isn't guaranteed to return 4-byte aligned memory either; you're relying on behavior the standard doesn't mandate. If you *can* use a C11 compiler (GCC >= 4.7) you could use [`aligned_alloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc)

Answer (score 1):

> what is the best way (in terms of performance) to allocate memory if you need multiple array of different data types?

- In case you need very large amounts of memory, the overhead of calling malloc several times is most likely neglectable and trying to manually optimize the calls is then most likely just pre-mature optimization.
- In case you don't need very large amounts of memory, use VLAs. These are typically allocated on the stack (compiler implements them by calling alloca or similar) so they are both way faster and way safer than dynamic allocation. For example:

  ```
  void local_function (size_t d_arr_n, 
                       size_t i_arr_n,
                       ...)
  {
    double double_arr [d_arr_n];
    int    int_arr    [i_arr_n];
    ...
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't know about this. But unfortunately, it won't in this case. The amount of memory I need to allocate doesn't have any specific range. It can be huge (in which case, my stack might overflow) or it can be tiny (in this case, malloc is a system call that might mess up my cache). Anyway, good to know the trick.

Comment: @Rakib Turns out you are most likely just doing pre-mature optimization then. Benchmark your program with likely input data and see where the actual bottlenecks are, before attempting any optimization. Generally, it is a very bad idea to use the same malloc call for non-related data. And if the data _is_ related, why aren't you using a struct instead?

Comment: You are right. It's not a bottleneck. I just got curious for how to do this efficiently when my code was giving me wrong result. I cannot use a structure because in this simple case, I said both arrays have the same length. In my actual code, all the arrays might not have same length.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

you have declared,

```
int *iA;
```

if you add a whole number, **N** to iA means, it will point to the **N**th **int** location. i.e,

```
dA = iA + N; // then, dA = iA + N * sizeof(int)
```

**Solution**

If you want dA point to a location iA + N then declare iA as **char *** instead of **int ***.

```
char *iA; // will solve the problem
```

If you are planning to use mixed data type (e.g. int and double) use **struct**.

e.g.

```
struct MixedType
{
int a;
double b;
};
```

then use malloc to dynamically allocate memory,

```
MixedType *iA = (MixedType *)malloc(sizeof(MixedType));
```

if you want array of MixedType of N size; then,

```
MixedType *iA = (MixedType *)malloc(sizeof(MixedType) * N);
```

assign dA as in your code,

```
dA = (MixedType *)iA;
```

you can access a & b in MixedType like,

```
int a = dA->a;
double b = dA->b;
```

Comment: You probably misunderstood. dA = iA + N; is what I actually want. So that dA starts where iA array ends. And as I mentioned in another comment, I cannot use structure because not all my arrays have same length.

Comment: So try dA = (void *)((char *)iA + ((sizeof(int) + sizeof(double)) * N));